# How to iterate over redis dictionary

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I know `Amazon ElastiCache Redis` maintains data in key-value pair i.e. in the form of `dictionary`. We can set a key-value pair and retrieve data as follows

```
from rediscluster import StrictRedisCluster

startup_nodes = [{'host': '<host>', 'port': '<port>'}]
rc = StrictRedisCluster(startup_nodes=startup_nodes, decode_responses=True)
rc.set('foo', 'bar')
print(rc.get('foo'))
```

But I need to iterate over the entire dictionary, how can we do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `scan`, or `scan_iter` ([doc](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#redis.StrictRedis.scan)):

```
def test_scan(self, r):
    r.set('a', 1)
    r.set('b', 2)
    r.set('c', 3)
    cursor, keys = r.scan()
    assert cursor == 0
    assert set(keys) == set([b('a'), b('b'), b('c')])
    _, keys = r.scan(match='a')
    assert set(keys) == set([b('a')])

def test_scan_iter(self, r):
    r.set('a', 1)
    r.set('b', 2)
    r.set('c', 3)
    for key in r.scan_iter():
        print(key)
        print(r.get(key))
```